# Solve nonlinear algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, pseudoinverse

I'm trying to find the best way to solve this equation for the vector $x$.

\begin{equation}
Ax+b-ty=0
\end{equation}

Where $x=[x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n]^T$ and $y = [\frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_2}, \frac{1}{x_3} , ... , \frac{1}{x_n}]^T$.

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix 
$b \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ 
$t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

---

My unsuccessful attempt so far:

1. Expand out each row, $i$ and multiply both sides by $x_i$
2. Now you'll have a linear set of equations with coefficients of $x_1^2$, $x_2^2$, $x_1x_2$ ...
3. Create the vector $X$ containing all quadratic permutations of $x$: $X = [x_1^2, x_2^2, x_1x_2, ... ]^T$
4. Rewrite the original equation as $\tilde A X = \tilde b$ and solve for $X$ using the pseudo inverse
5. Somehow get $x$ from the values of $X$

---

If this problem is too hard to solve. Let a simplified version be the case where $A$ is circulant.

Comment: Multiplying both sides of the equation by $x_i$ leaves the term $b_ix_i$, which isn't quadratic in $x$. Do you need explicit solutions or is numerical good enough?

Comment: Ah you're right. Ideally an explicit solution. But numerical approximation will do

Comment: I thought of another option: Define $X = [x, y]^T$. Then write in block matrix form: $[A, -tI] X = -b$. Then I can pseudo-inverse the matrix over. This isn't a good approach though because it doesn't constrain the solution to abide by $x_i y_i = 1$